# Python: How do I use tuples with scipy.optimize.minimize

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization

So I have got a problem formating the call of the function correctly.

The function I want to optimize has following structure:

```
def tooptimize(a,b):
    .....
    return c
```

a and b are both tuples with two values each (sadly can't change this). Both values of b are given and fixed.

I now want to minimize c while having some boundaries:   5<=a[0]<=8 and 4<=a[1]<=7

What my code looks like right now:

```
bnds = np.array([((5,8),(4,7)),((b1,b1),(b2,b2))])
b = np.array([b1,b2])
agues = np.array([(6,5)])
sol = op.minimize(tooptimize,aguess,b,method='SLSQP',bounds = bnds)
```

Of course I don't get a solution. I tried so much but nothing works and I don't find anything considering using touples with this function.

I hope you can help me. I am new to programming so pls don't be angry if there is a simple source for the solution.

Comment: There's multiple issues in the code, but first there's a conceptual issue. You never defined what `c` is, and you didn't apply any bounds to it. You only bound `a[0]` and `a[1]`. As it stands the optimal solution for `c` is simply `-infinity`.

Comment: I just did not copy the code in the function but c is a function of a[0],a[1],b[0],b[1]